# setLayoutParams for RelativeLayout encounter with error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-gridlayout

Hi I am newbe in Android. I have an XML layout file which contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/items_tab_fragment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:foregroundGravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_cancel_black_24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp" />
        <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.TextViewNumericFont
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:hint="0"/>
        <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.EditTextFont
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:hint="نام کالا یا سرویس(اختیاری)"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/keys_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridKeys"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:numColumns="4"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            app:useDefaultMargins="true"
            app:columnCount="4"
            app:rowCount="4">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_layers_clear_black_24dp"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="3"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="9"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="8"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button11"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="7"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="0"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="4"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_backspace_black_24dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:padding="30dp"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="3"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button5"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="6"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button6"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="5"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button12"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="4"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="1"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/button13"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_box_black_24dp"
                android:padding="78dp"
                app:layout_column="3"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="2"
                app:layout_rowSpan="2"
                app:layout_rowWeight="2" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button7"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="1"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="2"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button8"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="3"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="2"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="2"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button9"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="2"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="2"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />



            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button14"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="000"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="0"
                app:layout_columnSpan="1"
                app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                app:layout_row="3"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

            <com.arosis.pos.aropay.customization.ButtonRezvanFont
                android:id="@+id/button15"
                style="?attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="@drawable/back"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_column="1"
                app:layout_columnSpan="2"
                app:layout_columnWeight="2"
                app:layout_row="3"
                app:layout_rowSpan="1"
                app:layout_rowWeight="1" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to change the height of "key_layout" programmatically like the following:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        screenUtility = new ScreenUtility(this);


        RelativeLayout gridKey = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.keys_layout);

               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gridParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 200);
    gridParam.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    gridKey.setLayoutParams(gridParam);




        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                viewDetailFragment();
            }
        });


        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("سفارش"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("فهرست"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        Typeface tabsFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/iransans.ttf");

        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.getChildCount();
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++) {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup) vg.getChildAt(j);
            int tabChildCount = vgTab.getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildCount; i++) {
                View tabViewChild = vgTab.getChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild instanceof TextView) {
                    ((TextView) tabViewChild).setTypeface(tabsFace);
                }
            }
        }


        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        final DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                } else {
                    drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
            }
        });


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        //        Screen Utility
        ScreenUtility screenUtility = new ScreenUtility(this);
        if (screenUtility.getDpWidth() >= 820) {
            mTablet = true;
        }

        if (screenUtility.getDpWidth() < 820 && screenUtility.getDpHeight() < 820) {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        }

    }
```

But when I launch the app, it will be stopped! and when I remove the setLayoutParams line it works correctly.

## LogCat Error:

```
Process: com.arosis.pos.aropay, PID: 10773
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.arosis.pos.aropay/com.arosis.pos.aropay.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3253)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
 at com.arosis.pos.aropay.MainActivity$override.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
 at com.arosis.pos.aropay.MainActivity$override.access$dispatch(MainActivity.java)
 at com.arosis.pos.aropay.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:0)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6876)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1135)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3206)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3349) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5382) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:221) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1800) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

What should I do?

Comment: post the stacktrace or at least what kind of exception youre getting

Comment: put your logcat error

Comment: LogCat Added to the context!

Comment: Did u intialize gridKey?

Comment: Yes I have gridKey

Comment: @altruistic Can u post little more code of that activity? From starting

Comment: @altruistic did u use proper layout xml in setContentView of that activity?

Comment: @altruistic u have updated your code right? Now in which line u r facing the issue?

Comment: `gridKey.setLayoutParams(gridParam);`

Comment: @altruistic not getting error at RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) gridKey.getLayoutParams()?

Comment: When I comment `gridKey.setLayoutParams(gridParam);` it becomes OK.

Comment: @altruistic I have asked a question in the previous comment?

Comment: But I change also it, to the above, but also problem

Comment: @altruistic can u post your whole activity_main.xml?

Comment: I added the whole XML

Comment: @altruistic can u put a break point at RelativeLayout gridKey = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.keys_layout); and check gridKey has value or not?

Comment: try to clean and rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the gridKey variable is null. The only way this can happen that I see is that `R.layout.activity_main` does not contain a RelativeLayout with an ID of `keys_layout`. Double check the code you are posting is not from an intermediate directory. Then do a clean and try it again.